# Is there a way to use css image filters on just a part of an image?

Tags: css, image-processing, imagefilter

I'm wanting to select just a part of an image and apply a css image filter to it.
I could cut up the image in squares and apply a filter to one, but I'd like a way to apply a filter to any size selection in the image.
Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean when you want to apply a filter to any size selection in the image?

Comment: Any size selection within the images boundaries.